# Exception has occurred: TypeError 'float' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, gis, gdal

i'm trying to to get pixel values at a set of coordinates in python with a
landsat images,  my coordinates are of type float, and it does not let me make the corresponding calculations but I cannot see the error, the code throws me "Exception has occurred: TypeError 'float' object is not subscriptable"
I'm using the gdal module

```
import os, sys, time, gdal
from gdalconst import *
startTime = time.time()
xvalues = -103.6238888889
yvalues =  19.3344444444
directorio = str (input("ingrese el directorio de la imagen "))
os.chdir (directorio)
gdal.AllRegister()
ds = gdal.Open('AST_L1T_00302242018173601_20180226112641_11826_T.tif', GA_ReadOnly)
if ds is None:
   print ('Could not open image')
   sys.exit(1)
rows = ds.RasterYSize
cols = ds.RasterXSize
bands = ds.RasterCount
transform = ds.GetGeoTransform()
xOrigin = transform[0]
yOrigin = transform[3]
pixelWidth = transform[1]
pixelHeight = transform[5]
for i in range (1):
    x = xvalues[i]
    y = yvalues[i]
    xOffset = int((x - xOrigin) / pixelWidth)
    yOffset = int((y - yOrigin) / pixelHeight)

    s = str(x) + ' ' + str(y) + ' ' + str(xOffset) + ' ' + str(yOffset) + ' '
    for j in range(bands):
        band = ds.GetRasterBand(j+1) 
    data = band.ReadAsArray(xOffset, yOffset, 1, 1)
    value = data[0,0]
    s = s + str(value) + ' '
print (s)
endTime = time.time()
print ('The script took ' + str(endTime - startTime) + ' seconds')
```

Comment: The error message means that you are treating something as an array, which is actually a number. I.e, you are doing something like `a[x]`, where `a`  is a number. The error message probably included a line number. (Next time, include that in the question, and preferrably the full traceback!). Now look at that line, and think about what you are `[]`:ing in it.

Comment: As @TurePålsson says, you try to access xvalues[i] and yvalues[i] in your loop, when these values are floats.